# Need advice for good free-download WYSIWYG text editor for website in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What's a good WYSIWYG text editor for ASP.NET MVC, with possibility to add pictures, I can download for free to use in my application so that those who are not developers can add content to the website. By good ones, I mean those which can be used without to many configuration, simple ones.

Some people might point out that this questions has been asked already. However, the answers date from over 10 months ago. So, unless nothing has changed since, please what to do at this time

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). It's used in many of the main content management systems such as Umbraco.

Comment: @Brian Scott: I've just checked the TinyMCE link you posted above. Now witch version do I need to download to learn how to use it? (Main package, JQuery package, development package, ???...)

Comment: @Richard77, personally I like the jQuery syntax as I can drop a textbox onto the asp .net page in multiline mode. Then you simply call the jquery functions on textareas on the page to replace them with the full rich text editor.

Comment: @Richard77, also, here's a fully worked example of integrating TinyMCE in an ASP .Net page.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IntegratingTinyMCE.aspx

Comment: @Brian Scott: Can u point me to pages where I'd see how to use TinyMCE with ASP.NET MVC? Thanks

Comment: @Richard77: The example URL I sent you contains a simple tutorial on how to set the TinyMCE up in a normal ASP .Net page. You can simply create a control template in your MVC app which does exactly the same thing and call it using ViewPage.LoadControl(). Just because it's in MVC doesn't make the implementation any more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you've answered my question. More has to come, but I'll do it through other posts.